# How to disable body scroll on mobile menu when open?

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll, menu, responsive

I'm creating my website responsive for mobile except when I open the menu I see the scrollbar on top of the menu pop out and I can still scroll on the body that's behind the menu. I would like to hide the scrollbar and prevent the body from scrolling when the menu is open. I've seen examples how to do this with jQuery but is there a way to do it with just plain JavaScript or even css? I've also tried using **z-index** on the menu but that doesn't work either. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The css property is overflow: hidden. Apply that to your main content when the menu is open.

Comment: @CharlesBamford I tried that but its still showing when its open, any way to do it with JavaScript?

Comment: The problem isn't that overflow: hidden doesn't work, it's that it's being applied in the wrong place, or that code somewhere else is countermanding it. Any js solution will boil down to adding that property, as that is how the browser is instructed not to scroll. It would be better to figure out why overflow: hidden isn't working than to try to figure out how to work around it.